# What will be the impact on API traffic and cluster health by enabling an audit event eval?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

For one of my use case I need to enable `eval` event in a 20 node cluster where auditing is already enabled. I'd like to go ahead and enable the `eval` event and provide the audit logs to someone, however, I'm concerned about the impact on the cluster that it will cause.
Will it effect cluster health? There are already 11 events enabled at present.

Answer (score 1):

The impact of the auditing will at least partially depend on how your application code is written.  If there are a lot of `eval` calls, then it will have a larger impact, then if there are very few `eval` calls.

If there is a concern that auditing evals will impact performance too much, then you can limit how many events will be audited by only including or excluding certain users, groups or by document URI.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/auditing#id_23562

As always, changes should be tested prior to implementation to determine what the impacts may be on production systems.

Comment: Restrictions to events are generic. Is it possible to limit just one event while leaving the rest as it is ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Exclusions/Inclusions are applied to all the enabled audits.

Comment: You mentioned 'audit events' but not the intended use other then 'to give to someone' There are more flexible, and possibly more suitable/faster then audit logs.  Ask your support rep for information on system events which can be enabled on your sever.  These are primarily internal debug logs -- so not intended (or supported) for true "Audit Logging" - if the use case, however, more aligned with performance and use metrics they may work better for you.  
In V9+ there is also a new subsystem for use metrics which is *highly efficient*, sets of user definable named 'counters' .  Not a timeline.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following to provide a measurable methodology for safely and objectively determining the impact of changes one suspects may affect performance, and how to isolate the issue.  The intent is to provide a 'plan of action' that should help satisfy the team that making changes of this nature are generally non-invasive and 'safe' -- providing you have a methodology to validate the affects, isolate the root cause and rollback if needed *before* any possible performance issue gets out of hand.

A critical part is knowing (or by 'educated guess') what to expect, how to look for it and what to look for that might occur if your wrong.
In your case my 'educated guess' is that enabling audit logs on Eval() will have negligible performance impact (assuming the system is currently working well, below its maximum capacity, volume storage for the logs have predictable IO rates, system configuration is 'standard' etc)

Audit events have roughly the same overhead as log events.  For the most part, the codepath is simple and bypasses most system code writing directly to the audit log.  In a single-threaded workload the results should be deterministic and measurable.  While you wont get a 'per audit log' time easily (you cant inject them back to back to measure), you can get fairly fine grained measurements by looking at before & after timings of well-known events such as request times.  This allows you to answer the question conclusively *for your workload*. For auditing eval, I would expect the overhead to be very small compared to the eval call.  (less then 0.1 % -- educated guess).   This depends on the media you are writing to, if its encrypted or not, remote/local etc, how much contention and locking are done.  Why so low ? Eval statements incur a significant performance cost to set up and tear down the evaluation context, manage multiple transaction states, then the added parser overhead, marshaling values across contexts etc.  You can measure this in QCOnsole easily.  Given that, if your using evals, its 'best practice' to do so on fairly corse operations (i.e not 1+1). That leads to fact that the overhead of running an eval is a rate limiter, compared to the overhead and IO of an audit log.  Im going to guess at *minimum* 100x more likely 10000x -- so I pulled 0.1% from an orifice, ill buy you a beverage if its off by > 10^2  -- should be validated, see below.  You might be able to measure the cost of a 'generic audit log' by enabling one associated with a very lightweight operation, then writing some tests that excersize that in a loop.  That will give you the minimal baseline, but should not be used for much else -- its not realistic, so results of other factors like overall performance impact, contention etc should not be taken as indicators of what *your use case* will do.

what could go wrong ? Even a tiny lock/contention-point CAN trigger a system-wide breakdown in concurrency -- *IF* that lock happens to be one that is in the codepath of a large number of threads that are doing nothing else but just that -- and that they are 'pushed' faster then the system can execute them, and if the timing is such that they all hit the same lock at the same time over and over.  Generally a set of dice rolls you could take to vegas and get rich on -- by wagging it will never occur.
Sometimes, it ALWAYS occurs -- the exact cause is typically easy to determine *after the fact* -- but how to prevent ?  basic engineering -- hypothesize, test, measure.

In a highly parallel application which is doing audit logging simultaneously in multiple threads/cores there will be a higher per-call overhead due to contention on the audit log itself.  How much -- will depend to high order based on the degree of contention, which in a simple highly parallel case can occur spontaneously --  is a feedback loop.  ( one thread blocks writing to log, causing another thread to block waiting for the first, and so on)   In the *extreme case* (extremely unrealistic, but possible -- not hard to create intentionally)  this could eliminate most or all of the performance gains by having multi core.  Its very UN-likely any real application would have the exact conditions necessary,  but knowing this as a edge case is useful for predictive measures.  You can take baseline measurements and then intentionally over-saturate the system concurrently, aiming for the simplest *identical* operations occurring in every thread and push it until you start to see non-linear performance issues.   That is the indication of reaching the threshold were performance may degrade quickly. (and non-linearly, possibly exponentially).  Stay away from that 'knee' in the graph and your good to go, with actual reproducible metrics to validate.  Note that the onset of such an event is often *very non linear* -- i.e system working on a 32 core light load going fine for months the at say 3:02 every day -- nothing much changes except system load maxes out, connects latency increases quickly until hitting session timeouts or backlog limits then stays flat at that load.  Per-core CPU usage shifts to a single (or few) cores leaving the overall system appearing almost idle but throughput at 100x or worse.  That kind of behaviour can really annoy people :)
Its extremely uncommon ( you will not likely experience it *ever* even during load tests). But IMHO, its good to know what to look for just in case you luck out on the magic mix of conditions -- very easy to spot this behaviour, and likewise, almost always just as easy to prevent or fix, if you know what to look for.

Note this same statement, and measurement technique, is applicable to *any* operation in the server that potentially needs to synchronize across threads  (most operations do need some small amount of synchronization that is usually unmeasurable at the application layer). Occasionally, particularly in performance tests where identical workloads are executed in step-lock and pushed as fast as the server will take them, a 'hot spot' in the synchronization may be hit which will cause a collapse of asynchronicity  (a 'log jam').  These are not common, the server is written very well to avoid these cases, but it is not possible to entirely eliminate them (while still maintaining data integrity and  good multicore performance).   If you do encounter such a situation, you can spot the cause usually by looking for this kind of nonlinear change of performance across the server as more threads are brought online.  Particularly if the workload is a 'Push' workload (clients constantly oversaturating the servers capacity).   A first triage for a fix is to add some 'noise' (or 'jitter' ) to the workload ( i.e. simulate real client behaviour with sporadict requests of variable nature),  lower the number of threads (if you see backlogs), then enable traces and look at call-chain/stack dumps and log output to identify the offending operation (usually it will be a single core primitive all threads are waiting on.  )

Finally, note the pre-conditions at the beginning. THis is not exhaustive.  There are *many possible* system configurations that throw all the above in the trash.
Not *good* configurations, but possible ones. 
Extreme case, if your log files are network mounted, or on removable or flakey hardware (say an aged SAN drive over iscsi) - taking the volume offline is going to hang the server very quickly -- if audit logs occur in all application threads ...
Or say you've mounted all of /opt/MarkLogic/Data on a S3FUSE mount then unplug the network -- the above (while still true) will not be the leading cause.